# Can we have a set of 'editor tools'?

Tags: feature-request, edits

Could we have some 'editor tools' that make it quicker/easier to edit?

As a frequent editor (<s>almost</s> Copy Editor on SO), I'd like:

- Code Indenter/Formatter
- Spelling and grammar check, excluding `code`. You can use technical/"Hacker" dictionaries to remove the chance of "polymorphism" being identified as an incorrect spelling.
- Converting:

  - This:

    ```
    a, b, c, d
    ```

    to:

    ```
    `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`
    ```
  - `I SCREAM FOR ICE CREAM!` to `I scream for ice cream!`
- Search & Replace (Normal; Extended C-style `\r\n\t`; Regex)

  - Have a sidebar of common/saved Regex patterns/replaces.
- Underline potentially removable/editable phrases, such as:

  - `Please help`
  - `Thanks/Regards, [name]`
  - `........?????!?!?!?!?!`
  - `WT[FH]`

It would make editing more fun, and I would be able to edit a lot more.

Comment: I use Chrome, and it already spell-checks for me automatically.  I get the little sqiggly under the misspelled word (in fact, I just got one under "sqiggly").  Just sayin'.

Comment: +1 for search and replace. It *might* be the browsers vendors who should solve this, but I'd **love** to be able to do some search & replace. Occasionally I even copy the entire post body to a text editor to do this, but it's just enough effort to not be fun.

Comment: @Robert Yeah, same, but I have to run the text cursor over all the text first.

Comment: Use Firefox, and you don't have to do the stupid cursor thing.

Comment: @Shog9 I'll never join you! *Neveeeer!!*

Comment: +1 specifically for the `\`a\`, \`b\`, \`c\`` suggestion, which is annoying to do even in `vim`.

Comment: Off topic: w00t! Just got 1000 rep on MSO. My thanks to the 7th upvoter.

Comment: All I care about is removing bloody tab characters. Everything else I can deal with efficiently enough.

Answer (score 8):

There was a [great editor toolkit](https://stackapps.com/questions/2209/se-editor-toolkit) - which was available as userscript. The inline editor broke the editor and it hasn't been updated.

Given the vast number of edits I do, I decided to port it over to the desktop - you can find [it here](https://github.com/SathyaBhat/StackEd). By no means it's complete or "pretty" - it's functional & allows me to continue with my edits.

Of course, you will have to copy & paste the content to the editor, but once you click correct, the edited version will be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: OS X version ftw!