# Can we have find and replace in the editor?

Tags: feature-request, editor

I'd like a "find and replace" function in the post editor. As it stands, I copy it into Notepad, apply Find & Replace, and copy it back. That's a little inconvenient. Just a simple one would do, for those answers whose solutions are to, say, double backslashes, and there are a lot of them.

Comment: What kinds of things are you using find and replace for? I don't believe I've ever needed to use a find and replace before.

Comment: @animuson: One recent example is when the problem was unescaped backslashes. I would have liked a simple replacement of `\` to `\``\`. (Ugh, can't even get it right in the comments! \ escapes \ but not \`... sometimes.) Another example might be replacing newlines with `<br />` in long blockquotes.

Comment: Some kind souls have written a userscript that you can find over at [stackapps](http://stackapps.com/questions/2209/se-editor-toolkit) for this purpose.

Comment: @jonsca: Write that as an answer, 'cause it's correct for now! Thanks! +1

Comment: An avid user of the script @sathya reported in a comment to my now-deleted answer that it [breaks under the inline editor](http://stackapps.com/questions/2209/2482#2482), so I'll leave the suggestion as a comment.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Can we have a set of 'editor tools'?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106242/can-we-have-a-set-of-editor-tools)

Comment: @Dori I don't think so, if only because that's one of those dozen-suggestions-in-one omnibus posts.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use the built-in find function of the chrome and other browsers. It gets you where you want. But it doesn't provide the replace functionality. You might checkout the [webstore for extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore) if there is any such extension for find and replace

Comment: Well, at least on Mac/Safari, [the WMD editor breaks "Find Next"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100349/on-mac-based-browser-command-l-should-select-the-address-bar/) (i.e., **⌘G**). I'd like to see *some* replacement for that, given that they've removed the browser's built-in functionality.

Comment: So? If it doesn't provide replace, I may as well continue using Notepad. It's not like I can't find them manually, and the browser's find function is either a) broken, as Dori points out, or b) finding instances outside of the editor, too.